# How can I (install and) use the cloop device in Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel, mount

I need to be able to mount and read on the fly a compressed `dd` image. I think that `cloop` is what I need. But I don't see it in `/lib/modules` and, anyway, I'd like to know how it works first.

Anybody has already managed to mount a compressed image and read it on the fly via `cloop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't include the `cloop.ko` module needed to have a *compressed loopback* device. However, it's very easy to add it to the running kernel.

I found it on [this page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloop/2.6.39.2-1ubuntu1) (not sure if it's the latest version but compiles and works well), so I wget'd and uncompressed [this file](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/cloop_2.6.39.2.orig.tar.xz). The `configure` seems to be already included inside the `Makefile` so running:

```
make
```

is enough to build the module correctly. The package also contains the `advfs` utility, the original name for the command `create_compressed_fs` whose synopsis can be found [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/advfs.1.html).

I copied the modules in `/lib/modules` with:

```
sudo cp cloop.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`
```

but this step is not mandatory. Then one can choose to use the `advfs` or install the ubuntu package `cloop-utils` that provides the same utility with another name. I chose the package option because it's cleaner (I also suggest to install `pv` to have a nice progress bar):

```
sudo aptitude install cloop-utils pv
```

Now the compressed image can be created through the `create_compressed_fs` utility, and can be subsequently assigned to the `/dev/clooop0` device passing the filename as parameter to the module `cloop.ko`. Honestly I didn't find a better way to pass the filename to the `cloop` module and this poses a problem if one wants to mount multiple compressed images in different time frames. However, for the moment I don't have this problem, so this script has been more than adequate for my needs.

```
#/bin/sh -e

INPUTDEVICE="/dev/sda1"
OUTPUTFILE="/tmp/dev-sda1.cloop.img"
BLOCKSIZE="1048576"
NUMBLOCKS="2000"
COMPRESSIONLEVEL="9"
#COMPRESSIONLEVEL="-1" # for 7zip compression (untested)
CLOOPLOGFILE="/tmp/cloop-creation.log"
CLOOPBLOCKSIZE="64K"

dd if="$INPUTDEVICE"  bs="$BLOCKSIZE" count="$NUMBLOCKS" | pv -s "$((NUMBLOCKS * BLOCKSIZE))" -Wpetr | create_compressed_fs -L "$COMPRESSIONLEVEL" -B "$CLOOPBLOCKSIZE" -s "$NUMBLOCKS"M - "$OUTPUTFILE" > "$CLOOPLOGFILE" 2>&1

insmod /lib/modules/`uname -r`/cloop.ko file="$OUTPUTFILE"

mount -o ro /dev/cloop0 /mnt/cloop
```

Some other information can be found on the Knoppix wiki about `cloop` devices, [here](http://knoppix.net/wiki/Cloop).